# Svg image became negative when I reshow it

Tags: javascript, svg, sass

I have a main svg that open popups when I click on some elements in it, but if I close the popup, the colors of the main svg became really weird, I don't know what cause this, it's the first time that I see that

The index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="svg-container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <div id="svg-popup-container" class="svg-popup-container"></div>
    <script src="../js/utils.js"></script>
    <script>
      fetchSvg("main-svg");
    </script>
</body>
```

And the utils functions I use to display them

```
function fetchSvg(name) {
  fetch(`../assets/${name}.svg`)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      document.getElementById("svg-container").innerHTML = data;
      setupSvgContainer(name);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error :", error));
}

function setupSvgContainer(basePath) {
  addEventToElementsById(
    ["close", "background", "back"],
    "click",
    hideSvgPopup
  );
  setupInteractiveElements(basePath);
  document
    .getElementById("svg-container")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      if (!event.target.closest('[id^="eye-"], [id^="i-"]')) {
        setupElementsDisplay("infotext-", false);
      }
    });
}

function addEventToElementsById(ids, eventType, eventHandler) {
  ids.forEach((id) => addEventToElement(`#${id}`, eventType, eventHandler));
}

function addEventToElement(selector, eventType, eventHandler) {
  let element = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (element) {
    element.addEventListener(eventType, eventHandler);
  }
}

function hideSvgPopup() {
  toggleDisplay("svg-popup-container", false);
  toggleDisplay("svg-container", true);
}

function toggleDisplay(elementId, show) {
  let element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if (element) {
    element.style.display = show ? "block" : "none";
  }
}

function setupInteractiveElements(basePath) {
  setupPopups("eye-", (event) => showPopup(event, basePath));
  setupPopups("i-", showPopupInfo);
  setupElementsDisplay("infotext-", false);
}

function setupPopups(prefix, eventHandler) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="${prefix}"]`).forEach((popup) => {
    popup.addEventListener("click", eventHandler);
  });
}

function showPopup(event, basePath) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let svgToFetch = event.currentTarget.id.split("-").slice(1).join("-");
  console.log(svgToFetch);
  const svgName = `${svgToFetch}`;
  fetch(`../assets/${svgName}.svg`)
    .then(checkResponseStatus)
    .then((svgData) => {
      const svgPopupContainer = document.getElementById("svg-popup-container");
      svgPopupContainer.innerHTML = svgData;
      toggleDisplay("svg-container", false);
      toggleDisplay("svg-popup-container", true);
      setupSvgContainer(basePath);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("Erreur fetch :", error));
}
```

And the css just in case :

```
.svg-container,
.svg-popup-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  & svg {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I can bind part of my picture before I open the popup and after I hide it. It looks like that :
[mainSvg before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfoAE.png)
[the popup with the cross to close (loaded when I click on the eye)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2ofU.png)
[mainSvg once I close the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyFrP.png)

EDIT :

I try to load both of the image at the same time by doing so :

index.html :

```
 <body>
    <div id="svg-container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <div id="svg-second" class="svg-popup-container"></div>
    <script src="../js/utils.js"></script>
    <script>
      fetchSvg("main");
      fetchPopup("second", "svg-second")
    </script>
  </body>
```

utils.js

```
function fetchSvg(name) {
  fetch(`../assets/${name}.svg`)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      document.getElementById("svg-container").innerHTML = data;
      setupSvgContainer(name);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
}

function fetchPopup(name, id) {
  fetch(`../assets/${name}.svg`)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
}
```

And like that, "svg-container" has its color changed, but if I switched svg-container and "svg-second", then the "svg-second" has its color changed

Comment: I imagine you have duplicate id values or duplicate class names. All id and class names need to be unique.